# Publishing of JS files on tomcat in eclipse

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, tomcat

I want my javascript files to publish automatically when I change them. The problem I am facing is when I keep the Publishing settings to "Never publish automatically", eclipse does not publish anything (which looks to be expected) . But when I keep the settings to "Automatically publish when resource changes", it publishes js files and restarts the server as soon as I change a java file to make the java changes effective. I end up waiting for 2-3 mins of server startup time for my project. In such a scenario both settings are appearing to be not useful to me.

Is there any setting by which I can avoid the java changes to get effective till the server is restarted but the JS changes start appearing without a restart ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, keep the publish resources option and disable "Modules auto reload by default" from the "Server Options" section in the same view (bottom).

[image]